# How to settext in arraylist

Tags: android, arraylist, hashmap, settext

I've tried many possibilities and none worked. It needs to change the third value so that when the list is displayed immediately changed values

JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

```
            JSONArray devices = jsonObj.getJSONArray("list");

            for (int i = 0; i < devices.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = devices.getJSONObject(i);
                String id = c.getString("id");
                String name = c.getString("name");
                String known = c.getString("known");
                String description = c.getString("description");
                String controllerId = c.getString("controllerId");


                JSONObject frequencySurvey = c.getJSONObject("frequencySurvey");
                if (frequencySurvey.has("5000")) {
                    JSONObject fivezero = frequencySurvey.getJSONObject("5000");

                    String timestamp = fivezero.getString("timestamp");
                    String clients = fivezero.getString("clients");
                    String enabled = fivezero.getString("enabled");

                    HashMap<String, String> device = new HashMap<>();

                    device.put("id", id);
                    device.put("name", name);
                    device.put("enabled", enabled);
                    device.put("clients", clients);

                    DevicesList.add(device);

                }


ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Devices_5_0.this, DevicesList,
            R.layout.list_item, new String[]{ "name","clients","enabled"},
            new int[]{R.id.name,R.id.clients, enabled});

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

In third values I get values "false" or "true" and i want to set false = Not active but true = Active

OnCreate

```
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.enabled);
        DevicesList = new ArrayList<>();
```

And global declared:

```
 private ListView lv;
private TextView tv;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> DevicesList;
```

Comment: Where is your boolean arraylist?

Answer (score 0):

try this in the condition of for loop

```
DevicesList.add(i,device);
```

instead of

```
DevicesList.add(device);
```